# How to add Loading Indicator to Android Picasso?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I use [Square Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) like this:

```
  Picasso.with(context)
      .load(url)
      .centerCrop()
      .fit()
      .into(imageView);
```

I want to have a rotation loading indicator while Picasso loads the image. I tried the solutions posted here:

[Animated loading image in picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826459/animated-loading-image-in-picasso)

[Show an "Loading..." image while background loading of image with Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655245/show-an-loading-image-while-background-loading-of-image-with-picasso)

I created an animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_image"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"/>
```

and put this animation inside my `Picasso`call:

```
Picasso.with( context )
        .load( your_path )
        .error( R.drawable.ic_error )
        .placeholder( R.drawable.progress_animation )
        .into( image_view );
```

My problem is that the animation is not running. Also it is not a tiny loading indicator in the middle of the image, instead the loading image is stretched to the dimensions of the image.

**How can I add a Loading Indicator to Android Picasso?**

Comment: Use a different form of animated drawable, such as [an `AnimationDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html). "Also it is not a tiny loading indicator in the middle of the image, instead the loading image is stretched to the dimensions of the image" -- you would need to set up your drawable to have padding as desired. There might be attributes for that with `animated-rotate` (I haven't seen or used that); for `AnimationDrawable`, you supply the frames and so would put the padding in the frame images themselves.

Comment: Could you please post an example in an answer?

Answer (score 2):

progress_animation.xml -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/progress_image"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"/>

and use picasso like this - 

Picasso.with(this).load(imageString).placeholder( R.drawable.progress_animation ).into(imageView);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to animate